# Laravel Mail::queue Exception with message 'Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-mail

In my laravel app I have created a helper for sending email.

Helper Code:

```
public static function send_email($page,$subject,$email,$email_data) {
      try {

        $site_url=url('/');

        $email_data['site_url'] = $site_url;

        Mail::queue($page, array('email_data' => $email_data), function ($message) use ($email, $subject) {
                $message->to($email)->subject($subject);
        });

        \Log::info("Email Sent ");

    } catch(\Exception $e) {

        \Log::info("Email Error ".print_r($e , true));

        return Helper::error_message(109);
    }
}
```

I was trying to update composer via composer update command after that my mail function stopped working and giving this exception error message:

```
[2018-03-09 11:21:22] local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' 
with message 'Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted 
(tried to allocate 252182528 bytes)' in /home/ubuntu/thumbtack-base/app/Helpers/Helper.php:708
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
```

Whats wrong with my code?

Comment: which version you are using?

Comment: Its Laravel  5.2.45

Answer (score 0):

2 possible scenarios .
1) You are getting into an infinite loop which exhausts your memory.
2) You are exhausting your memory limit you have set.

If you upgraded **php** when upgrading **laravel**  keep in mind that `php 5.6 && 5.7` have a set limit to memory you can use.
Check the `memory_limit` you have.
If you run laravel via nginx also make sure the `memory_limit`is set to nginx

Comment: Site is hosted on Apache2

Comment: Check this https://tutorials.hostucan.com/how-to-increase-php-memory-limit/

Comment: In my case its 256M. What value should I set here? Have no Idea.

Comment: That s something I can't answer.It s up to your mail functionality and how many mails you want to send . Try 1 GB for example

Comment: In this case you should start debugging stuff.Something when you updated laravel caused the problem.try check older issues on laravel github

Comment: I am very surprised that forgot password email is working properly, but email from Helper function is not working.